# track GA event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I've read numerous subject here about that topic but I feel like I'm the only one with that issue...

I've implemented event tracking with jQuery and it works "fine" but the event tracking occurs when the page load although I've put the code in a jQuery "click event".

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.mailto').click( function(event) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'contact', 'email', 'Agence '.$(this).attr('id'), 500, false]);
});
```

});

Any idea why is it acting that way ?

Comment: Just for information, it's not working when I click on any link (a href) with the class "mailto" on it... Weird :(

Comment: From what you've shown, your code works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ZS9XY/) The callback function does not get executed until you click on the `.mailto` link. If the event does indeed get fired on page load, it's because of code that you haven't shown. If you are using google analytics debugger for Chrome, keep in mind that a "page tracking" event will get fired on every page load, but that's not the same as the event that you are tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... I've tested it on Chrome, Firefox and other browsers to be sure and with always the same result :( The event in GA is the right but it's call on pageload... You can see the result here : [link]http://mws.mywebshop.org/contact/[/link] (with user/mdp as mws/mws)

Comment: You need to provide a test case that can be reproduced (either in the form of a jsfiddle or a link to the page where you're having the problem), because the code that you posted works fine.

Comment: I've edited my comment for that purpose ;)

Comment: I've confirmed that the event does not get fired on page load. I see, using the google analytics debugger, that a `pageload` event gets sent to google on page load.

Comment: What makes you think this event gets fired on page load?

Comment: I'm logged in in GA and monitoring event with the real time monitor... And each time I refresh the page I see an even is triggered, the exact same event as the one in the code :(

Comment: The event is not getting fired on page load. I can confirm this. As to why you're seeing something show up in GA analytics real time events, I don't know. But it's not because of that code on your contact page.

Comment: Download the Google Analytics Debugger extension for Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en and, when it's on, you can see exactly what events are getting sent by looking at your console.

Comment: Well I've run tests in the mean time and the event does not show on click neither... It should occur when you click on one of the footer link (mailto...). What's wrong with my js ?

Comment: It has bugs. Look at your console, see the error, and debug it.

Comment: I'm using Wordpress with the plugin "Google Analytics for Wordpress", maybe it's sending some tracking (although i've uncheck everything) ?

Comment: You're right, I've done some clean-up and it's now working ;)

Comment: But I'm still having that awkward event tracked on page load... I can't identify where it comes from. I'm guessing it might be a widget but would you have any tips ? Thanks again,

Comment: @FabienPelissier I see 2 hits happening on page load: 1 is from your on-page code and the other is from your `sharaholic.js` script. Looks like sharaholic has its own GA tracking, probably to see how many people use their script.  You can see the hits have 2 diff acct #'s on them...

Answer (score 0):

I do not see event tracking on page load.  But I do see 2 hits happening...on is yours, from your on-page code. The other is from `sharaholic.js`. Looks like sharaholic has its own GA tracking, probably to see how many people use their script. You can see the hits have 2 diff acct #'s on them..